# ¿Cómo puedo actualizar solo un fragmento de un registro y no el registro entero?

Tags: mysql, sql

Verán, necesito arreglar caracteres erróneos en una db. Ya he corregido la mayoría, sin embargo, en el caso de que me falten, me gustaría saber si se puede actualizar solo un fragmento de un registro por sql.

Tengo aquí mi tabla de ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y su código por si la quieren replicar:

```
TRUNCATE `pruebas2`;

INSERT INTO `pruebas2` (`id_pruebas2`, `descripcion`) VALUES
    (1, 'Me parece que esto es estÃºpido'),
    (2, 'La desolaciÃ³n que sintiÃ³ cuando abriÃ³ la caja fue mayÃºscula'),
    (3, 'Tengo una anÃ©cdota, pero no te la voy a contar'),
    (4, 'No me gusta ni la quÃ­mica, ni la fÃ­sica, ni la biologÃ­a'),
    (5, 'Tengo un Ã±andÃº en el garaje, estÃ¡ borracho');
```

Intenté actualizar los registros así, pero no funcionó:

```
UPDATE `pruebas2` SET descripcion = '%ú%' WHERE descripcion like'%Ãº%'
```

Me dejó esto:

[image: ![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En resumen, si se puede hacer, me gustaría saber cómo; y si no, si se necesita un procedimiento almacenado con funciones del estilo de substring, split y otras.

Comment: Quiza puedas lograr lo que necesitas, utilizando `REPLACE(descripcion, 'Ãº','ú')` aunque tambien deberias revisar el encode al momento de hacer el insert, digo, para evitar que esos caracteres lleguen a tu DB. Saludos.

Comment: Como bien dice @JosueArriola deberías ir a la raíz del problema, para determinar por qué motivo los datos están llegando mal codificados y corregirlo. Insertar datos así en la BD es exponersa una infinidad de errores aparte de tener que programar código adicional para tratar de corregir un problema sin ir a la raíz del mismo.

Comment: Sí, llevo días en esto y el problema es de hace 5 años atrás. Tengo que arreglar el utf-8 en la conexión de PDO y arreglar la codificación de las tablas (la del servidor ya se corrigió), ahora me queda arreglar los datos que ya estaban insertados y hay varios tipos de codificaciones. -.- Casi todo eso lo tengo planificado, en un rato que no se utilice el sistema aprovechar de actualizar en producción.

Comment: Gracias @JosueArriola, funcionó. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias a Josue Arriola ya tengo la respuesta, era así:

```
UPDATE `pruebas2` SET descripcion = REPLACE(descripcion, 'Ãº','ú') WHERE descripcion like'%Ãº%'
```